# Fitting Ideal $\mathrm{Fit}_n(M)$ annihilates $M$

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have the following question about a step (red tagged below) in the proof concerning the Fitting ideal (here the source: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07Z6).

[image]

Why $\mathrm{coker}$ of the linear map $A'$ is killed by $n$ if the matrix relation $A'B = f I_{n \times n}$ holds? And how does this imply that $f$ annihilates $M$?

Comment: $M\simeq R^n/\mathrm{Im}(A')$. Let $x\in R^n$ Then $A'(Bx)=fx\in\mathrm{Im}(A')$, so $f(R^n/\mathrm{Im}(A'))=0$.

Comment: I think it should be "killed by $f$" instead of "killed by $n$".